# Entity Data Model Wizard requires app.config and ignores custom T4 templates

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF6 and Database First, I created custom T4 templates (*.tt files) in my VS2013 class library project. I don't want to migrate the app.config file with my assembly so I delete it. When I Update Model from Database, it presents me with a connection to select (I believe this is stored in the Visual Studio user preferences). If I choose not to store this in the app.config, it continues to show this step in the Wizard. Whenever the connection selection step is presented and the wizard completes, I notice the EDMX generates the two default *.tt files alongside my custom ones. Any way of preventing this? I read an article about EF code-based configuration and I tried DbConfiguration.SetDefaultConnectionFactory but that didn't help. The EF wizard always wants a connection in the app.config. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why not just keep it in the app.config?

Comment: As part of my client's best practices, it was determined not to pollute our production environment with a config file for each assembly, especially if the only thing it's needed for is a reference to a development database used for design purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up leaving it in the app.config (on my machine) and do not migrate this file to our development/test/prod environments. It's become a manual task to confirm each app.config file since it has become necessary to migrate some files due to adding project assembly redirects.